# Oh no! The mods are gone! (and Rand al'Thor, too!)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, steganography

> Dear Puzzling Users,
>
> Oh dear, where start? I guessed it started with my feelings that the mods are way too overbearing. And then I realized, "Hey, I don't have to put up with this sh*. I can just get rid of them all!" So that's what I did: I kidnapped all your moderators plus Rand al'Thor just for kicks. Now, I get that I have to leave "clues" or whatever bull crud I have to put up with, so FINE! HERE ARE YOUR RUDDY CLUES Y'ALL! BUT I'LL SOON TAKE OVER ONCE I CAN GET THE MODS TO HAND OVER THEIR POWER HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA
>   Have fun!!!!!!!!
>
> **Deusovi**:
>   So the other day, my sis and I were playing poker. She's a notorious cheater though, so she decided to cheat by throwing some parsl*e*y at me. Yeah, I know. She's kinda dumb though. Anyhow, it landed on my eye, and in return, I la*n*ded a nice slap on her back. Didn't go well with my mom, though, when my sister started to wai*l*, crying, "Whale!" Kinda random. Then my mom started going berserk saying, "Show me the car*d* ag*a*in! Show me the card again!" Then she said in a weird So*u*thern accent that my sister was the winner! What the heck?
>
> Oh you want Deusovi's location? Here: "*Read and puncture the beginning, heart of a German man named Ing*" (3, 7)
>
> **Rubio**:
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
> **GPR**:
>   Ontop of a very boring rainbow,
>   Lays Gentle Purple Rain.
>   He was like the 16 French kings:
>   Dead.
>   Oh the misery of his passing,
>   So clueless was he to wander so close to Rubio
>   And yet so far away,
>   Ontop a very boring rainbow
>   Ontop of an entranced doorway,
>   On a very rainy day,
>   Laid Gentle Purple Rain,
>   Shivering in the rain.
>
> **Gareth**:
>   [image][image]

^See edit note on the bottom^

> **Rand'AlThor**:
>   You know me quite well, I hope,
>   After all, I warn you of the hags
>   By singing you a song.
>   And if the sky was clearer,
>   You could see the whole city from up here.
>   What am I?
>
> Bet you could never figure out where they are.  Ha! Rescuing them - that's funny.  I'll see you later when I'm dictator of Puzzling SE
>
> With Love,
>   North

Hint 1:

> What's that hidden behind's Gareth's picture? What are hags? 16 French kings?

Hint 2:

> Deusovi's is a giant wordplay and play-on-words. Also, every single mod *besides* Deusovi (because he's special) is in, on, below, around, at etc. a landmark. Regarding Rubio's — three of them are wordplay. If you can figure it out, the rest should become easier to deduce.

Hint 3:

> In GPR's puzzles, there are only a few important key words to lead you into the answer.In Rand's riddle, everything is of pertinence.

Hint 4:

> These are massive hints I am about to reveal:
>  Rubio's puzzle are puns on states or monuments/places found in those states.
>  Gareth's puzzle is anoter wordplay. Read the lines carefully, and almost attempt to take everything literally. Consider what the Reverse-Flash says about himself, and it should give you the location.
>  Rand is somewhere in Britain.
>  Parsley sounds a lot like this one place found in a bay somewhere mentioned in that ridiculous story. Just remove the l in parsley. The italisized give you indicators of homophones as discovered by one of the commentors.

Hint five: Several edits. A photo has been added to the Rubio's puzzle.

> Deusovi is in Wales.
>  Reverse-Flash. Reverse flash. Reverse flash flash's name in reverse?
>  Hags ---> witches. Britain. Song. Tall building

---

> Note: Don't worry about the CC. It was just an attempt at a practical joke — it was *supposed* to be answered as RED HERRING. Of course, the CC was not a very good one, and is not necessary to solve this puzzle by any means.
>
> Edit: I'm really, really, sorry, fellow Puzzling SE. I for some reason, the image will not decode itself when imbeded into the question. There is some kind of mishap that happened, I am not quite sure how this happened. Please forgive me. In the meantime, the image that shoud've popped up when decoded should've been the Reverse-Flash picture.

Comment: The psychotic mailer also would like some feedback for some reason

Comment: So it's time to party? Excuse me while I go spam some questions hawking pills :-)

Comment: I've made some minor formatting changes to reduce the "wall of text" effect, please check to see that I've not altered the puzzle itself inadvertently. @North

Comment: @North I am not sure, but I think the waterfall is consisting of text: *KOME* or something like that.

Comment: You know me quite well, I hope,
After all, I warn you of the hags
By singing you a song.
And if the sky was clearer,
You could see the whole city from up here.
What am I?

Comment: I guess noone wants to find the mods. Rand al'Thor freed himself somehow.
As for the Deuvosy part, the italic letters are:
n  Landed
l   Wail
d  Card
a  Again
u  Southern

Comment: @North Wow, so you put Deusovi inside a fish? That's low. :P

Comment: Never mind..when he's found we'll have a rousing chorus of Whale Meet Again....

Comment: Can we just leave Deusovi kidnapped for a bit longer? It's nice getting to answer puzzles today.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhsRL.png

Comment: The puzzle is just saving Deusovi, once he's free he'll solve the 3 other parts anyway

Comment: Not sure how important it is, but according to [reverse Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivhhA08CpdGt429e7qgmjtk3Rq6CCqwX_1Lg3fiF8VyxrN5BYdcvOPE33WqwQ1zqga8N4biayyy9uL0ghG2pCCwCon51NjmQ-FZC3d-GxU6z0UolD-9NQVxTPlkDJ4hvXpDEaP8te8L2pTeecEdxmcjxd9LzHPabkak2AGiyA4dnvHkdM4Us1LL7KYvcvzuHdCEpkQ3O5JLbaYmeEmDtCvsSTv6pRd5ekhkyYazx5zBrC8rVfQz0l48k8HNDpHrLEOfw04Wd4hSeQvtKM3v6eEut1H4eNBC5cfVm9fHcygQfD3N8KHURDPmUQnbs7tsPfvG15WTvSV_1ds95VzIJWYo8eU7qd3g&btnG=Search%20by%20image&hl=en) Gareth's picture is Iguazu Falls.

Comment: @PL457 You missed "e parsley"

Comment: @Barker it's not Iguazu Falls that important, but rather what the Iguazu Falls *hide* behinds it

Comment: Major hints have been added

Comment: @North I've added a guess for Rubio's location, let's see if we can find him as well...

Comment: @Rubio $\diamondsuit$ is that Godzilla? heheh :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deusovi is

> In Cardigan, Wales. I just swooped in and stole this from the hints and all of Strawman's work. "Card Again" -> Cardigan, "Whale" "wail" -> Wales. and the hint saying it's in Wales and not a monument.

Rand is probably

> On Big Ben. Since it is in Britain, is tall sings a song "by chiming". The reference to witches is probably a warning about the witching hour. It is also one of the most well known monuments in Britain.

Gareth is

> At [Eastern Wall in Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Wall) Wally West in reverse is East(ern) Wall[y]

For Rubio is:

> At the USS Utah memorial at Pearl Harbor.

Because:

> 1000 Canons = Grand Canyon Arizona
>  No place like home = Kansas
>  Penny Wood = <s>Lincoln tree in Sequoia National park (Nevada)</s>  penny + sylvan = Pennsylvania
>  Frying pan = <s>Rose Hill, North Carolina, home of the worlds largest frying pan?</s> <s>Alaska</s> Oklahoma which is shaped like a big frying pan (thanks @thecoder16)
>  Should have left a virgin = West Virginia 
>  Red is the new gold => <s>El Dorado = city of gold => city of color = Colorado</s> 
>  Golden gate bridge is Red -> California (thanks @ffao)
>  
>  Definitely a pyramid => <s>Del operator + aware = Delaware. Very Mountain = Vermont</s>  Luxor Pyramid in Las Vegas, Nevada 
>  Elephant Socks => Mass wearing Chausettes (french for socks) > Massachusetts.
>
> ```
>  OK NV KS
>  AZ WV PA
>  ?? CA MA
> ```
>
> As the discussion in the comments have seen, these States seem to be about US battleships. USS Okalahoma and USS Arizona were completely destroyed, Nevada, West Virginia, and California were damaged, Kansas and MA were not present, and PA was also not involved. The remaining destroyed battle ship is the USS Utah, so Rubio is at the USS Utah Memorial at Pearl Harbor.

Comment: More precisely, Deusovi is on [Bardsey Island](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Bardsey+Island) ("parsley", "I landed") in Cardigan Bay. I'm not sure whether the oblique u in Southern means that he is in the croft at the southern tip of the island.

Comment: M Oehm is right! Nice! The first two for Rubio's is correct. The next two is incorrect. Penny wood is a play on words of the meaning of that state's name, and the frying pan is a joke on the geographical shape of that state. The important ones in Rubio's is the definitely and the well... kinda section. The well... kinda is a little sarcastic. The middle one is a major play on words.

Comment: Bounty has been awarded to this. Now i can rest in peace knowinh no one will rescue Rubio

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! I take it that means I found Rand and Gareth (with the help of a ton of hints)?

Comment: frying pan is probably bxynubzn (rot13)

Comment: I added some (probably closer) guesses for Rubio

Comment: What do you make of the grid and the Pearl Harbor map? I think we were supposed to find the PH map from the code that was there before, but I don't see how. Nine of the battleships have state names: UT, PA, CA, NV, AZ, TN, WV, MD, OK, and there is an overlap between your states and the ships' names.

Comment: That is a good hint, so I used that to refine a few answers and increase the overlap. There are still 4 missing overlaps though.

Comment: The guess for Red is the new gold is wrong, though the states share a same first consonant C. Wow, you really took Massachussetes more complex than I intended. It was supposed to be Elephant=Republican party = Red, +Socks or Red Sox in Boston, MA

Comment: @MOehm that clue is on the right track. However, the first two columnes are the that are the most important. Th last one is what it was NOT.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the ships. I think OK is a better fit than AK, but whether NV is better than VT is debatable. And North has confirmed that KS is right, but there's no such ship. KS is in the "heck, no" section, but PA, which is a perfect fit for "Penny wood" is there, too. Some of the clues are very loose: the virgin one could be both WV or MD, where the left part of the name is Mary. (I wrote that 10 mins ago, but was delayed in posting it.)

Comment: Let me make it more clear: What do USS Arizona, USS Neveda, USS W. Virginia, USS Oklahoma all have in common? How does USS Arizona and USS Oklahoma differ from USS W. Virginia and USS Neveda?

Comment: "Definitely": USS's Arizona and Oklahoma were destroyed in the Pearl Harbor attack; "Kinda": USS's Nevada, W. Virginia and California (?) were damaged, but could resume service later; "Heck No": USS's Kansas and Massachusetts were not involved and USS Pennsylvania was in the dry dock and withstood major damage. AZ and OK were the only total lossed in the attack, so I don't know what to put in place of the ????.

Comment: @MOehm Utah was also destroyed.

Comment: Also Red is the new Gold is CA, because of the Golden gate Bridge.

Comment: I see. (Apparently it was already decommissioned and used for target practice.) But Utah is a bit vague as Rubio's whereabouts.

Comment: Who said Rubio's in the memorial site? Have you tried swimming underwater?

Comment: Fun fact, in GPR's puzzle, I mentioned GPR being so close to Rubio yet so far away. Well, USS Missouri is docked on the other side of Ford Island near USS Arizona.

Comment: @North, any chance you can let us know what the grid was meant for? Was it meant to be a hint towards battleship?

Comment: @wolfram42 The grid was for you to put the picture on the grid to get a precise point according to my made up coordinates. But whatever. I drowned Rubio anyways.

Comment: @North You monster!  $$\def\T#1{\text{#1}}\small\begin{array}{c}\T{~~~~~~~,~°~~~~~}\\~~~ \T o ~~~~°~~~~\T O ~~~\dot~~~~~  \T o \\ ~~~~~:~~~\T o ~.~~~~\cdot\\~~\T o ~ \dot~ \\\T {ヽ(°□°-)ノ}\end{array}$$

Answer (score 13):

I'm a first-time lurker and so probably very wrong, but here are some wild stabs in the dark mostly to get ideas going!

**Deusovi**:
I'm going to guess

> Parsley Island

although I don't have a strong justification for it. In Hint #2,

> his clue is mentioned as "wordplay and play-on-words," which is a repetitious phrase, just with the words reversed. The clue itself has many repeated phrases, such as "landed on my eye" - "I landed," "kinda dumb" - "kinda random," "wail" - "whale", and the entire "show me the card again!" phrase twice. "Card again" could mean "cardigan," or I could be looking for homophones too much.

In the text itself,

> there are various italicized letters in words, specifically: e in parsl*e*y, n in la*n*ded, l in wai*l*, d in car*d*, a in ag*a*in, and u in so*u*thern. e n l d a u is clearly an anagram for "eu land", so we just have to comb all of europe and we'll find Deusovi ;D In these words, everything but "parsley" and "southern" are used in repeated phrases, but this could be me overlooking something or chasing false leads.

We can ignore the final part, because

> 'a' is the 3rd letter of the 7th word, so if we follow the instructions and puncture that out, our first word is "Red." A German man named Ing would be "Herr Ing," so we have Red Herr Ing. Typical that the misdirect is the only one I'm certain of solving correctly!

**Rubio**:
I'm at a loss here. Two phrases I recognize as

> references to shows/movies, where "Red is the New Gold" could be "Orange is the New Black," and "There's no place like home" is the famous phrase Dorothy said in "The Wizard of Oz." I have no idea what the columns, graph, or scrambled letters are for, however.

**GPR**:
Another shot in the dark, but are they perhaps at

> the arc de triomphe?

My very loose reasoning is that

> the poem references both a rainbow and an entranced doorway. In French, "rainbow" is "arc-en-ciel," and I imagine a very boring one would be gray and missing all the usual colours. The "arc" could also reference an archway, which is a kind of doorway.

However, this can always be wrong because

> It doesn't really use the 16 French Kings clue, other than the "French" part of it. This line could be a false lead, but the final king of France was Louis XVI, so maybe "Louis" is the important part to glean?

**Gareth**:
As stated in comments, this is

> Iguaza Falls.

Some googling says that

> This location was used for Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull, so maybe there's a secret kingdom with a crystal skull hidden behind it or something. I've never seen the movie (I know, *for shame!*) so I cannot really comment on that. It could also be a false lead and the falls have something else hidden!

**Rand al'Thor**:
I don't have a specific place, but is it

> some kind of storm warning site, or a weather balloon?

My line of thought is that

> hags could be witches, but it could also mean storms in old Irish tales or something like that. A tornado siren or storm alarm would warn you of them via an iconic sound, but the rest of the clue suggests it would be somewhere high up. I don't know of any iconic landmarks that fit this criteria, though, so I'm quite possibly chasing a dead end!

Thank you for the puzzle either way! I'm certain that I'm very far off, but hopefully this can be the springboard to get someone else to the proper answers.

Comment: Wow. You are actually semi-close. First of all, welcome to Puzzling SE! Please take the tour, you will also earn a badge! Um, last I checked, there is such place as *parsley* island. But Cardigan sounds awfully like card again...

Comment: Your guess for Rubio and Gareth is completely off, but GPR's guess is actuallys on the very right track indeed. There is a keyword in there that will lead you into the correct answer (you mentioned the word yourself)! Rand al'Thor's location is completely off, but hags are witches indeed

Comment: Also, please register, you'll keep track of your badges and reputations!

Comment: hm about 'eu land', apparently that's what 'utopia' is supposed to mean... I think. Please don't kill me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Building on Wandering Strawman's answer, my guess is that GPR is hidden

> on top of the Gateway Arch in St.Louis

Because

> The Gateway Arch is gray, so quite a boring rainbow, and is in a city whose name is the same as Louis XVI. Plus, "Gateway" really resembles the meaning of "entranced doorway".

About Rubio:

> ! As wolfram42 said, 1000 Canons = Grand canyon. I add: Frying pan = Oklahoma (because of its shape) and ????? = Area 51.
>   Could Rubio be in the Colorado river somehow? No idea about the two other pictures, however...

Comment: Humph. Yes, you've found GPR tied down to the top of giant arch. I wished I could've dangled him hanging off, but it would be too noticable, and plus, it's hard to use the internet when you are hanging by the neck with people pointing at you. Annnnny ways, you've recovered GPR. Congrats. But you've still got four more to rescue. Hee hee hee!

Comment: Fun fact, there are also 16 French Kings all with the name King Louis, which is why it says "Like the 16 French Kings"

Comment: @North yaaaay! Now to the quest for the other four! Yes, of course they are 16, I don't know why I focused on the last one (maybe because nobody never remembers Louis IV or X)

Comment: Well "Saint Louis" is actually Louis IX. And there was in fact a Louis XVIII (Louis XVII never ruled). But you might need to be French to know that.