# A little bio with a secret

Tags: steganography

> So, let me tell you a bit about me. I have been online for most of my
>   life—IRC, muds, forums, the web, games, MMORPGs, etc.—but I've met the
>   brainiest people of all *right here* on this site! I am so happy to
>   have joined this website almost a year and a half ago. Now it is
>   my second home! When my cat was ill you gave me sympathy, and when
>   he died, your comments on my puzzle for him brought me comfort.
>   Until *I* pass, I just want an acre at Orlando, a cat, wifi, and my iPad.

**What else about me have I told you?**

Comment: That you've escaped from [North's puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64001/oh-no-the-mods-are-gone-and-rand-althor-too) :-) ?

Comment: I have allowed Rubio internet access... for now

Comment: Along with your cat, wifi, and your iPad, would you like Diet Coke? :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've told us ...

> ... that you are **the most silly puzzle creator**. I mean, the puzzle has a steganography tag, but the first letters of each line spell "slbhmhu" and there are not enough dashes for Morse code – how silly is that? `;)`

Erm, surely that can't be right, no?

> The bio is organised in lines and the lines alternate between having 51 and 50 letters. The middle letter of the first line, the two middle letters of the second line, the three middle letters of the third line and so on spell:
>
> `soletmetellyouabitaboutme  i  havebeenonlineformostofmy`
>  `lifeircmudsforumsthewebg  am  esmmorpgsetcbutivemetthe`
> `brainiestpeopleofallrigh  the  reonthissiteiamsohappyto`
>  `havejoinedthiswebsiteal  most  ayearandahalfagonowitis`
> `mysecondhomewhenmycatwa  silly  ougavemesympathyandwhen`
>  `hediedyourcommentsonmy  puzzle  forhimbroughtmecomfort`
> `untilipassijustwantana  creator  landoacatwifiandmyipad`
>
>  Very nice! More silly puzzles, please!