# My first steps to take over Puzzling Stack Exchange

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, chess

### This puzzle contains errors, the author is working on fixing this! Sincere apologies for the incovinience!

> Dear Puzzling SE Users,
>
> Okay so the [last time I tried to take over Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64001/oh-no-the-mods-are-gone-and-rand-althor-too) I failed. Yes the mods were rescued. How Rubio managed to survive drowning, and Gareth survive being buried alive, I don't know. I generously gave them access to WiFi, so maybe they found a lifehack to avoiding death. Who knows. Anyways, I have a new plan! And it'll be ingenious ... of course, you'll have to figure out how I'll do it this time. Of course, I doubt you will be (but again Deusovi is free so maybe not) but I WILL TAKE OVER. And to mark my celebration of future events (I don't care if it doesn't make sense) I'm showing off my latest chess game! Hahahahahahahaahahaha hmmmmm

[image]

> Yours truly,
>   North.

---

> Plaintext: 
>   [[WnQaHSVHRdsZaKD]
>   {KvrIhJqzHZiOdnzlpvgoJ1vItjoCZmkdzxZHjqZhzioNvMzzlpvgoj0}
>   [GroXGRsdowyFockZKGxkxnLvkmuboczyXNCgsDRkzkgxWYfowOxDyBGrsdowyfockZsomoKxnLVKmuBoCzyxncGsDRdrockwoZsOMoYbGROxgrSdomkcdvocKXnLvkmumKCdvocYXdrOckwoDebxYBEColsDgSCOpeXmdSyxYb]
>   [OzwFoZalwEgnwksfvTDsuCegnwkSvaXxwjwflhawuw/HsofmkwXMFulagfSfVAxOzalwUSKldwkSfvTDSucvGwkfglmkwKsewXMFulaGfskSTgnw]
>   [LwTcTxiwTghxstRPEijgthGteaprtujcrixdCLxIwMdg]
>   {ChUrlvhtXdoWrgrWdOORqhvDuhGDvKhv}
>   1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 Nc6 4. d5 Nce7 5. Be3 Bg4 6. Nbd2 Bxf3 7. Nxf3 Nf6 8. Bb5+ Nd7 9. O-O c6 10. c4 a6 11. Ba4 b5 12. c5 bxa4 13. Qxa4 dxc5 14. Bxc5 cxd5 15. exd5 Nxd5 16. Bxf8 Kxf8 17. Qa3+ Qe7 18. Qxe7+ Nxe7 19. Rfe1 Rc8 20. Nxe5 Nc6 21. Nxd7+ Kg8
>
> 1-0 White wins by resignation

Hint:

> Ave Caesar

Comment: To state the obvious, that text is certainly not FEN.

Comment: I ran the image [through OCR](https://pastebin.com/fqbTEZsj) if anyone is interested.. I have no idea if it's accurate.

Comment: If these are your first steps what do you class your previous attempt as?

Comment: Has been updated with a hint.

Comment: @L_Church Well, these are my *second* attempt, this lists my first steps to my new plan.

Comment: @North I thought we rescued Gareth. We were a bit slow on Rubio, but we managed to retrieve the body. Perhaps the wonders of modern medicine save their lives

Comment: @wolfram42 Or WiFi. WiFi has saved many lives.

Comment: @North so will this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gibberish can be decoded ...

> ... using the Caesar cipher. Each part between 2 brackets is using a different shift (25, 21, 10, 18, 15, 3 repectively). The decoded text looks like this (spaces added by me):
>
>  *[xor bitwise table]*
>  *{pawn movement is equal to 1 any other piece movements are equal to 0}*
>  *[when white moves a pawn and black responds with a pawn movement or white moves a piece and black responds with the same piece or when white castles and black castles on the same turn or use bitwise function or]*
>  *[when white moves and black moves a different piece/pawn use function and if white castles and black does not use same function as above]*
>  *[when either side captures replace function with xor]*
>  *{zero is equal to dot all ones are dashes}*

I tried to decode the moves ...

> ... using the information above (however, I have no idea what the first part is supposed to mean):
>
>  `1. e4 e5           1 or 1 = 1`
>  `2. Nf3 d6          0 and 1 = 0`
>  `3. d4 Nc6          1 and 0 = 0`
>  `4. d5 Nce7         1 and 0 = 0`
>  `5. Be3 Bg4         0 or 0 = 0`
>  `6. Nbd2 Bxf3       0 xor 0 = 0`
>  `7. Nxf3 Nf6        0 xor 0 = 0`
>  `8. Bb5+ Nd7        0 and 0 = 0`
>  `9. O-O c6          0 and (as above) 1 = 0`
>  `10. c4 a6          1 or 1 = 1`
>  `11. Ba4 b5         0 and 1 = 0`
>  `12. c5 bxa4        1 xor 1 = 0`
>  `13. Qxa4 dxc5      0 xor 1 = 1`
>  `14. Bxc5 cxd5      0 xor 1 = 1`
>  `15. exd5 Nxd5      0 xor 1 = 1`
>  `16. Bxf8 Kxf8      0 xor 0 = 0`
>  `17. Qa3+ Qe7       0 or 0 = 0`
>  `18. Qxe7+ Nxe7     0 xor 0 = 0`
>  `19. Rfe1 Rc8       0 or 0 = 0`
>  `20. Nxe5 Nc6       0 xor 0 = 0`
>  `21. Nxd7+ Kg8      0 xor 0 = 0`
>
>  This gives the following "Morse code":
>
>  `-........-..---......`
>
>  This is basically impossible to decode (assuming it is correct), because the letter separators are missing. The online tools didn't deliver anything, except of hundreds meaningless possible decodings.

Comment: Hmm. I must've screwed up somehow. *Sigh* I'm an idiot.

Comment: Sorry. This isn't your fault. My problem. I screwed up the XOR truth table and messed up the pairings. I also realized exactly how tedious it would be to break up all those Morse Code.