# I'm Back........!

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, music

To: My Mods! (and the community)
Note: The following is a letter enclosing the details of what's going on. It's more for "story" and humor, but does have some information that you might want. To save you time for those who'd rather not read the letter (and hurt my feelings), here is the tl;dr:

- The letter below does not contain any ciphers, steganography, or hidden messages.
- The music below contains a riddle. Some basic music knowledge will be required (i.e. know how to read sheet music in treble clef).
- The music contains all the information you need. The spots of red are "blood" and are purely aesthetic.
- That's it.

> Dear Puzzling SE,
>  Greetings! I'm back! Did you miss me? It's me, North, your favorite psychopathic tree!
>  After my humiliating [defeat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64001/oh-no-the-mods-are-gone-and-rand-althor-too) almost two years ago, I decided to take some time off for myself, thinking and plotting. Also being a tree. I was unable to post, because I lost Wi-Fi for a while. The service up here is terrible, trust me.
>  To mark my triumphant return, I figure I'd give you a little warm-up for our upcoming little game.
>  No moderators have been kidnapped... yet.
>  The music you see below contains a riddle. Yes, you'll need some background music knowledge, but what did you expect? That's the only thing I will tell you.
>  No clues nor hints have been hidden in this letter aside from what I'm telling you. No, seriously, everything's in the music, trust me. You're wasting your time by looking for clues here. Everything is within the music. Also, the spots of red aren't significant either. Just some blood. No biggie.
> Love you all dearly,
>  North

[image]

Hint:

> An ASCII converter table would come in handy. It's also in C major, not A minor.

Hint on the riddle:

> The word is four letters long. Each line either reveals a letter or reveals a definition, but not both.

Additional hint:

> You can try substituting "NOTHING" for "NAUGHT". There's a referen*c*e to degrees if you can catch it. Do you *s*ee it?

Update:

> Errors within the music. It has been updated and fixed.

Comment: Where's the YouTube video so we can hear what it sounds like :O

Comment: @Avi Haha! It sounds terrible, trust me. Everything’s visual. I wouldn’t expect you to listen and deduce anything ... yet, though that does give me some good ideas for the future. It’s too short to be worth uploading it online

Comment: "*Also being a tree. I was unable to post, because I lost Wi-Fi for a while.*" - you missed out on a great opportunity for a "post" pun.

Comment: the beginning measure has the right music time. Maybe transcribe it to notes?

Comment: @user118161 you’re on the right track for your train of thought

Comment: well yeah someone do that

Comment: @HTM the puzzle has been edited.

Comment: An additional hint has been added.

Comment: Someone do this, I forgot how to read sheet music years ago. I'm bad at riddles too, but those I can actually try.

Comment: an additional hint has been added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You

> sing a NOTE

Interpreting the score:

> Each bar is a word, and each group of 3 notes/rests is a letter. Each note/rest is a digit in base 8, with CDEFGAB mapping to 1-7 and a rest mapping to 0. A fermata represents the end of a line.

Doing this results in the following riddle:

> START WITH ME 
>  GO ON, HEAD SHAKING 
>  THE THIRD TO SEE 
>  IS LAST TO NOTHING 
>  FOR WHAT DO I SING?

Explanation of the answer:

> START WITH ME 
>  Your name is North, so start with an N. 
>  GO ON, HEAD SHAKING 
>  Head shaking means NO so the next letter is an O. 
>  THE THIRD TO SEE / IS LAST TO NOTHING 
>  This is the degree reference, the third degree on a C/See major scale is E, which the riddle says is the last letter to nothing/naught, i.e. NOT.

Comment: It appears that the two odd words are normal words with the replacement of one letter (the letter being shared between them)

Comment: Actually those are just typos. it should be "HEAD" and "NOTHING"

Comment: I fixed some typos. Those were errors on my part, not yours. Sorry!

Comment: I understand the degree reference but I'm pretty stuck on the other lines :P

Comment: edited with my answer @North

Comment: You're off by one letter, though I do like your answer better :P

Comment: I asked WHAT do I sing, not FOR WHOM

Comment: NO_E? I'm going to award you the checkmark because you got it, basically. Also, I don't want Myukyu's bounty to go to waste

Comment: just got back from work, edited again

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [cpark's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/93155/63153), here's what I found:

> START WITH ME
>  The first letter ("start") of "ME" is M
>
>  GO ON, HEAD SHAKING
>  Dropping ("shaking" off) the first letter (the "head") of "GO ON" gives OON
>
>  THE THIRD TO SEE
>  IS LAST TO NOTHING
>  ZERO ("nothing"/naught) has the last letter O. As we can clearly see, MOON has third letter O.
>
>  FOR WHAT DO I SING?

You

> sing for the **MOON**

Comment: Think naught as more like nought... you're on the right track, but the answer for every single one is completely wrong. Each line adds a specific letter. I will tell you you that the O and the N are in the word.

Comment: Corrections: one of the O's are in the right place, technically. The other just doesn't belong.